# Save instance state of activity to maintain user logged in?

Tags: java, android, session

I am developing an Android application that has a log in form and should maintain the user logged in. Basically what I have to do is make a request to an API and send the user email and password, that request returns a JSONObject which I manage just fine.

I have a **cookieStore** instance and save them into the user preferences through an instance of **SharedPreferences**, so every time I need the current user credentials I just get them from the preferences.

Thing is, if I close the app on my phone (I think that means to "pause" it, right?) I lost all my data which actually makes sense because **I'm never saving the instance state of my activities.**

My question is:

**What do I need to save into the instance state of my activities in order to maintain the user logged in? I could save the preferences? How do I do it? And also, is that suppose to be done on the onResume() method of each activity?**

Hope someone can help me with this, I'm just starting to develop in Android. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **SharedPreferences** and you don't want/need to save the current state of your activity you could simply get the values from SharedPreferences(if any) in onResume() method.

If you wan't to preserve the state of your activity, you must use the **`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`** method to save your data in the Bundle and in **`onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`** to get the data from the Bundle and populate your View's.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just realized my problem is my cookies get lost every time I close the application so when I make a new request to the API is like I never logged in. I guess I could just save the cookieStore instance in onPause() and restore it in onResume(), right?

Comment: onPause() does not give you access to the Bundle. you should use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) to save your data.

Answer (score 1):

data saved in SharedPreferences doesn't get lost when you close/destroy your app. just check for login details OnResume in the SharedPreferences. Don't forget to delete it from SharedPreferences when the user log out.

you could also save datetime of login in SharedPreferences and check it OnResume to see if user is timeout or not.